# How to change the color of already selected radiobutton from radio button lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list . Initially it's selected value is captured and stored to database. When I revisit the page , the radio button that I selected previously  will show as selected . Now I want to change /highlight the selected button with a different color .

```
<asp:RadioButtonList RepeatColumns="5" class="style_radio"   ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
    RepeatLayout="Table"  Width="100%">
    <asp:ListItem Text=""  Value="1000"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=""  Value="2000"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=""  Value="3000"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="4000"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem  Text="" Value="5000"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

On page load I have written like below,

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select selected_salary from staff_details where staff_id="ACD11" ", con6);
SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr2.HasRows == true)
{
    while (dr2.Read())
    {
         string salary = dr2[0].ToString();
        RadioButtonList rb = (RadioButtonList)Page.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
        rb.SelectedValue = salary;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand what you want, the purpose is changing the color/apperance of checked radio button, is that right? In this case, you can just define the css of checked radio button, something like:

```
[type="radio"]:checked 
{
     width: 16px;
     height: 16px;    
     background-image:  ...
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find which RadioButton is selected from RadioButtonList.Then add style attribute to it. Like:

```
foreach(ListItem li in RadioButtonList1.Items)
        {
          if (li.Selected)
            {
               li.Attributes.Add("style", "color: Green");
            }
        }
```